# How can I remove all properties of a user control?

Tags: vb.net

I am working on a Visual Basic project and I had to create my own user control. I want to remove-hide **ALL** default properties of this user control but not by using this `<Browsable(False), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)>` way, one by one property. I need something more massive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid what you want to do isn't possible in VB, as it would require to add the attributes dynamically (on all properties) and in VB attributes are static and cannot be added or removed dynamically.

The only way to do what you want to do is to add the attributes one by one property.

Comment: I wish that you are wrong my friend but I am afraid you are not!!! Let's see if someone else have any other idea... I mean can't we use something like for each etc? Also, there is any way to do this in C# or we have the same "limitation".

Comment: As VB and C# both run on the CLR, I doubt that it would be possible in C# or even in F#. But why exactly do you want to hide all the default properties of the UserControl?

Comment: To give you an example, I have make a **windows form title bar** user control that contains more than five controls. So in properties panel there are many useless properties or some of them doesn't exist. So I want to clear all this mess and make only my properties viewable. But, I think I have to do it one by one...